# Writing a file larger than block size in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

If I am trying to write a file of 200MB into HDFS where HDFS block size is 128MB. What happens if the write fails after writing 150MB out of 200MB. Will I be able to read data from the portion of data written? What if I try to write the same file again? Will that be a duplicate? What happens to the 150MB of data written earlier to failure?

Comment: It depends on the method you are using to copy your file to HDFS. Are you using hdfs shell commands or java code?

Comment: Actually this was an interview question asked to me which I couldn't find an answer. May I know about both the cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HDFS default Block Size is 128MB, if it fails while writing (it will show the status in Hadoop Administration UI, with file extension copying.)

- Only 150MB data will be copied.
- yeah you can read only portion of data(150MB).
- Once you reinstate the copying it will continue from previous point(if both the paths  are same and file name is same).
- For every piece of data you can find the replication based on your replication factor.
- Previous written data will be available in HDFS.